# Prove Monotonicity of a Recursive Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, monotone-functions

I have been banging my head against a wall for the last week trying to show that the following sequences, $c_n$ and $d_n$ are monotonic and that for any given $n$,   $d_n<c_n$. This seems to be the case numerically (to at least 10000 terms) but I have not been able to prove it using induction with the ratio of successive terms. Are there any other tools I can use to attack this problem that you could suggest?

\begin{equation}
 c_{n+1}=\frac{(36+8n)}{(4+2n)}(1+\sum_{k=0}^n\prod_{j=0}^k \frac{d_j}{c_{n-j}})
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 d_{n+1}=\frac{(8+2n)}{(20+8n)}c_{n+1}\prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{c_k}{d_{k}}+\frac{(16+4n)}{(5+2n)}(1+\sum_{k=0}^n\prod_{j=0}^k \frac{d_j}{d_{n-j}})
\end{equation}

with $c_0=14$ and $d_0=11$